# How to make some keyword in vscode to be italicized

Tags: visual-studio-code

So my friend & I are programming in Python. He has a code in python so here it goes: [image]

Somewhere in between some keywords like in def, there is some italicization.
How can I get this too?
I am currently using Arch Linux with vscode 1.61.2 with Jetbrains Mono font.
Here is my current behaviour[image]

Like in

```py
def change(x, y):
    "Change snake direction."
    aim.x = x
    aim.y = y
```

he has def italicized

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this does not appear to be a request for a code review.

Comment: vscode is build using electron which is basically a web browser without the adress bar and served locally. Styling is done through css. Any styling you can do in css is available within vscode as well. Ask your friend what theme they use as it's probably default for their theme

Answer (score 1):

add this to settings json

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "storage.type.function.python"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).